# Laravel 5.1 query related objects of multiple other objects

Tags: php, laravel, pagination, eloquent

I am using Laravel 5.1 with lazychaser/laravel-nestedset to create a parent/child tree of folders which works, but I am having trouble figuring out how to get the related posts for a folder and its descendants:

```
// first I get the folder
$folder = Auth::user()->folders()->where('slug', '=', 'some-slug')->first();

// Next I get the descendants, which gives me a
// collection of Folder objects
$descendants = $folder->getDescendants();
```

Now here's the problem. When I was just getting the related posts for a single Folder object, I did it like this:

```
// Where $folder is a single Folder object
$posts = $folder->posts()->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(100);
```

But I need to get the posts() for all the descendant folders as well, not just the one. Something like:

```
// Where $folders is a collection of Folder objects
$posts = $folders->posts()->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(100);
```

I need to get a collection of Post objects back that belongs to the initial Folder object and any of it's descendants, but I can't figure out how accomplish this with multiple Folder objects.

One solution might be looping through the Folder objects, creating multiple collections, combining them, then sorting them, but that doesn't seem like it would work because I am paginating, and the pagination has to happen with the query, not to mention, depending on how many posts there are, this would be way too slow.

**Is there a way to get the related Post objects for multiple Folder objects at the same time, or some way to do this I'm not seeing?**

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a foreach loop:

```
$posts=[];
foreach($folders as $folder)
{
  $posts[]=$folder->posts()->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(100);
}
```

Then you can collect them:

```
$collecttion=collect($posts);
```

Comment: This is what I initially tried, but the problem is the collection holds 2 paginated collections, so I get twice the number of posts because ->paginate(100) is run on them separately. Thank you for the reply, but I need to get a single paginated collection and looping through the folders gives me multiple ones.

Comment: @caleb-jacobo maybe you should paginate after collecting them.